# Remove grid lines from Winforms Chart

Tags: c#, .net

How can I remove chart grid lines in a `System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting` chart?

Comment: What is 'grinds' ? Do you means 'grids' ?

Comment: @leppie XAxis and YAxis grinds

Comment: I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: @Dudi: Those are 'grids', not 'grinds'.

Comment: @tomfanning Thanks, leppie I will keep that in mind, thanks for intrest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to set the `MajorGrid` and `MinorGrid` property for the respective axis to false.

like `chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;`

if you mean how to specify in the mark up then under chart areas

```
<asp:ChartArea .....
    <AxisX ><MajorGrid Enabled="false" /><MinorGrid Enabled="false" /></AxisX>
    <AxisY><MajorGrid Enabled="false" /><MinorGrid Enabled="false" /></AxisY>
</asp:ChartArea>
```

Comment: 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Grid' '

Comment: @Dudi Did you do as per the example you have to set the `Enabled` property of the Grid to **false** chartArea.AxisX.MajorGrid = false will give you the error above

Comment: What do you mean by *property in IDE* ? check out my edit hope this helps