# Asp.net charts- How to remove the background grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I'd like to know how to remove the background grid from asp.net charts, I haven't manage to find whats the property that responsible for that.
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove grid lines from Winforms Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598258/remove-grid-lines-from-winforms-chart)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this for your chart:

```
Chart1.ChartAreas["YourChartArea"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
Chart1.ChartAreas["YourChartArea"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
```